# How to extract the login info from this cookie?

Tags: cookies, hash, youtube

i was doing some security auditing using SSLSTRIP and the client had their password saved in a cookie, which got me thinking. So I on my account logged into YouTube and grabbed the LOGIN INFO cookie. For the benefit of my privacy i have censored part of the contents, just know that * represents one censored number. This was the contents:
`decee*****d0200a8c3f**f1bd2dea**c40AAAB7IjEiOiAxLCAiMyI*IDY0MDYzMjY0MywgIjIiOiAiSjVRRFdmUDR5ZFA1VjZZZHVvNUlldz**IiwgIjUiOiA*NTAzNjAxNzY2NDY1NTM2LCAiNCI6ICJHQUlBIiwgIjciOiAxMzE0ODM1MjI5LCAiNiI6IGZhbHNlLCAiOCI6IDI5NzEwMTU4Njg1N**`
I was wondering what type of hash this is, and if it is possible to decrypt? Just some plain old curiosity here, thanks for any replies or thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Youtube does not store user credentials in a cookie, that "hash" is probably just a random string used as [session id](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID), so there is no way you could "decrypt" the username/password from that string.

Answer (score 2):

Cookies should never be used for storing any login credentials. That cookie probably contains some session information that is checked on server side.